# If i own my own airstrip and have a friend from another country that owns a private jet, can they enter the country and land on my airstrip?

Tags: faa-regulations

So i'm just curious as to what would happen if i owned a private airstrip on my own land and wanted a friend from another country to come visit. Could he just simply fly to me without a visa or anything? Or would it have to go through customs? And what would happen to someone that just flew onto my airstrip without telling anyone? Would anyone even notice?

Comment: The US Government has at least one entire agency that looks for stuff like this: the DEA.  They get help from the Coast Guard, for boats and "submarines", and the Air Force for aircraft.

Answer (score 4):

They would need to [first file a flight plan to cross the ADIZ](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/us_restrictions/airspace/) or else they will get intercepted before making it to your field. Once they have filed the appropriate flight plane they can then only land at an [airport of entry](https://www.cbp.gov/contact/ports). You also need to supply your APIS manifest.

> All civil, private aircraft entering the U.S. must first land at an
> airport of entry before continuing to their destinations, unless other
> arrangements are made with U.S. CBP. Advance notification must be
> provided electronically to CBP by means of the eAPIS. See the APIS
> section for more information.

In other words an airport that has customs. You can however make other arrangements with CBP as noted `unless other arrangements are made with U.S. CBP`. So you might be able to land at your private field but you will need to arrange that with CBP prior to the flight.

[AOPA has a nice primer on crossing borders here.](https://www.aopa.org/-/media/files/aopa/home/go-flying/cross-border-flying_v8.pdf)

---

> And what would happen to someone that just flew onto my airstrip without telling anyone? Would anyone even notice?

[Yes, they would notice...](https://www.norad.mil/Newsroom/Article/2328902/norad-conducts-three-intercepts-of-russian-aircraft-entering-air-defense-identi/)

Comment: Also they notice and act on this sort of thing: https://www.cnn.com/2020/07/13/us/meth-bust-ultralight-aircraft-trnd/index.html

Comment: I’m pretty sure the “other arrangements” means a Customs User Fee airport; they’re not going to come meet you in some random farmer’s field.